# 1 TB Seagate External hard disk drive not showing data, says drive needs to be formatted?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

I have 1TB Seagate external hard disk drive. The hard disk drive is not showing the data and it says the drive needs to be formatted. What are the options available to me for data recovery and cost involved. The data to be recovered is 931 GB; mostly pictures and videos.

Comment: Have you tried using it with a different computer? Perhaps a friend's? Or a different OS?

Answer (score 1):

If Windows wants to format the HDD then most probably it cannot read its partition. It's likely that the data is damaged or the HDD is suffering from bad sectors. You might try booting a live Linux CD – it might be able to mount the partition so you can pull the data.

The biggest chance of recovering the data would be if you decide to use the services of a data recovery company. Check if the HDD manufacturer  offers such kind of services and/or if the have companies that offer discount for those drives. The price of DR can vary a lot and depends on the amount the data you want to recover and the complexity of the recovery process.

Answer (score 1):

As long as we talk about the external drive, and you said that your main task is the data recover, i recommend you (if other advices will not help) to carefully disassemble the external drive case, take the hdd and connect it to desktop pc. You have big chance, that hdd is in good condition and problem is in the external hdd box.

If you use laptop and have no desktop pc, you can request your friend for assistance or use any sata-usb adapter.

Answer (score -1):

Seems that the hard disk may have bad sectors, you should seek some professional recovery service. The cost of recovery depends upon the extent of damage and its not depended on the data amount that has to be recovered. In your case 931 GB, the specialist will check for bad sectors.

Best of luck.. hope you get the data back